# How can I get notified when log4j fails?

Tags: exception, log4j

like http://www.experts123.com/q/is-log4j-a-reliable-logging-system.html said: log4j doesn't throw any unexpected exception at run-time. If I want application infomation to be logged to a remote host, when the remote host is not reachable for network interruption or its ip address is changed, I want to send a mail to notify network administrator or switch to other appender like DailyRollingFileAppender.

since I can't catch the exception, so what else should I do to make me get notified when log4j  fails ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it.
use DOMConfigurator to configure FallbackErrorHandler, a spare appender when log4j fails.

I first use PropertyConfigurer but it warns that FallBackErrorHandler is not a proper element, I don't know why, but it worked well when change to DOMConfigurator.